# Programmatically get data access speed when requesting data from the API

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I build a simple android application showing data from TMDb API using Retrofit, but how do I programmatically get data access **speed** when requesting data from the server and show it on Android studio Logcat?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var apiKey : String
var movies : MutableList<Movie> = mutableListOf()
var adapter = MovieAdapter(movies)
val movieService : MovieService = ApiClient.getClient()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    rvMovie.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
    rvMovie.adapter = adapter

    apiKey = getString(R.string.api_key)
    getPopularMovies(apiKey)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

fun getPopularMovies(apiKey: String) {
    val call : Call<MovieResult> = movieService.getPopularMovies(apiKey)
    getMovieData(call)
}

fun getMovieData(call : Call<MovieResult>) {
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<MovieResult> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<MovieResult>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "${t.toString()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<MovieResult>?, response: Response<MovieResult>?) {
            if (response?.body() != null) {
                movies = response.body()!!.movies.toMutableList()
                adapter = MovieAdapter(movies)
                rvMovie.adapter = adapter

                // HOW DO I MEASURE THE DATA SPEED TRANSFER
                Log.i("speedtest", "Data transfer speed is = 99Kb/s");
            }
        }
    })
}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoB52.png)

Comment: First, use @streaming, in retrofit. then create a while loop and sample the length of the inputstream/buffer.   And Welcome to HarshOverflow

Comment: thanks for your response, but can you explain more detail please ? i'm new at this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Streaming // make you add this, since you are downloading movie
@Get("bla/bla/bla") // any Http method you are using
fun getPopularMovies(apiKey : Int)

...

// where you consume the apiservice
val call : Call<MovieResult> = movieService.getPopularMovies(apiKey)
getMovieData(call)

fun getMovieData(call : Call<MovieResult>){
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<MovieResult> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<MovieResult>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "${t.toString()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<MovieResult>?, response: Response<MovieResult>?) {
            if (response?.body() != null) {
                val moviebytes = ByteArray(1024 * 1024 * 1024) // also try this val bytes =                      byteArrayOf() if does not work
                val inputStream = body.byteStream();
                val numberOfbytes = inputStream.read(moviebytes)
                log(Log.i("speedtest", "Data transfer speed is = ${numberOfbytes}bytes/s");
            }
        }
    })
}
```